# Finding Orthonormal Basis for Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Find Orthonormal basis for the following vector spaces:

A) The range of the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ which sends $x \to Ax$ where $A$ is: \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\\1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}

B) The nullspace of the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ which sends $x \to Ax$ where $A$ is: \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\\1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}

I understand that for part B, the null space can consist of only the zero vector. I know how to complete the magnitude part of the equation, I am just stuck getting to that point.

Comment: kindly share with us what have you tried.

Comment: Most people don’t like to see a naked statement like this, with its implicit demand for a solution. You should say what your background is; what you’ve tried; and where you’ve gotten stuck. You should also make it clear to what extent you understand the relevant definitions and concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
The column of $A$ are linearly independent. Then, the range is just the span of of columns of $A$.

2) The nullspace of $A$ is formed by all vectors \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}
such that $Ax = 0.$ This turns to be a system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}
x = 0\\
x+y = 0\\
y = 0
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x = 0\\
y = 0
\end{cases}$$

Then, the nullspace contains only the zero vector.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that B was the zero vector I was just unsure if I could express that with the row reduced functions.